# Why is that: $P \Rightarrow T$, truth value(P) = ?, but $(P\Rightarrow F) \Rightarrow$ Truth value (P) = F

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Why is that:

If:

P :proposition.

T: true statement

F: false statement

$$P \Rightarrow T   $$ In this statement, we can not have for sure the Truth value
 of P (if P is T or F) , but, in this statement $$P\Rightarrow F$$  P must be false.

Comment: Because the truth-table for the *conditional* : $\Rightarrow$ has $FALSE$ only in case : $TRUE \Rightarrow FALSE$.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the truth-table of $P\to Q$:
$$\begin{array}{cc|c}P&Q&P\to Q\\\hline T&T&T\\T&F&F\\F&T&T\\F&F&T\end{array}$$
As you can see, if $\text{TruthValue}\left(P\to Q\right)=T$, you cannot conclude on $\text{TruthValue}(P)$. But the only way to have $\text{TruthValue}(P\to Q)=T$ when $Q$ is false is to have $P$ false too.

Now, you can think of implication (the $\to$ connective) as saying: "*it is never the case that when $P$ is true, $Q$ is false*". This is precisely what is meant by the second line of the truth-table. All other cases are allowed.